# How to calculate previous 12 months' sum value from this table using hive query language?

Tags: sql, hive

```
month   first_member
201612  135054
201611  250507
201610  296114
201609  317501
201608  427143
201607  449202
201606  398261
201605  419880
201604  393784
201603  459383
.....
```

Here is my table which has two columns. I want to calculate the previous 12 months‘ sum of first_member for  a given month. For example, the new table's one record includes 201605 and the sum of first_member between 201505 and 201605. So how to wrire the query to create the new table.
The month is string type and first_member is int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to split the `month` column when it is in `YYYYMM` format.

```
select  "month"

       ,sum(first_member) over
        (
            order by  "month"
            rows      between 12 preceding and 1 preceding
        ) as running_total

from    tablename
```

Comment: Thanks , run perfect

Comment: I am sorry that the code runs error on another dataset. I open a new question with data pasted. Could you please help to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217071/hive-time-window-functions-bug

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sum` window function. This would give you the previous 12 months sum of first_member for each month.

```
select month,
sum(first_member) over(order by cast(substr(month,1,4) as int),cast(substr(month,5) as int)
                       rows between 11 preceding and current row) rolling_sum 
from tablename
```

Edit: Per OP's comment *I want to include 201505 but not include 201605*
, the change needed would be

```
select month,
sum(first_member) over(order by cast(substr(month,1,4) as int),cast(substr(month,5) as int)
                       rows between 12 preceding and 1 preceding) rolling_sum 
from tablename
```

Note that this assumes the first_member has a value for every month between the specified time frame.

Comment: Is the time window include 201505 not include 201605 ?

Comment: if you want the first_member of 201505 in the result, use `12 preceding` in the window specification, instead of `11 preceding`.

Comment: Actually, I want to include 201505 but not include 201605. So how can I modify the query.

Comment: you said you dinn want to include 201605 for 201605. the query shown calculates the sum from 201505 to 201604..where as your condition calculates from 201506 to 201605.

Comment: Thanks. Run perfect.